# iOS accelerometer in the background (infinite)

Tags: iphone, ios, background, accelerometer, multitasking

I would like my app to monitor my accelerometer for an infinite time (even in the background). When it reaches a certain amount, I would like to deliver a local notification. This is exactly the same functionality as the 'Sleep Cycle' app has.

But how did they do this? When I use the beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler function, it isn't working anymore after 10 minutes. Adding UIBackgroundModes doesn't help at all.

```
UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
bgTask = [app beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
    [app endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
    bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
}];

_motionManager = [[CMMotionManager alloc] init];
_motionManager.accelerometerUpdateInterval = 1;
NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
[_motionManager startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue:queue withHandler:^(CMAccelerometerData *accelerometerData, NSError *error)
 {
     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
         NSLog(@"%@",accelerometerData);
             if(accelerometerData.acceleration.x > 0.5){

                 UILocalNotification *localNotif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];

                 if (localNotif == nil)
                     return;

                 localNotif.fireDate = [NSDate date];
                 localNotif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];

                 localNotif.alertBody = @"Wake up!";
                 localNotif.alertAction = @"wake";

                 localNotif.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
                 localNotif.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 4;

                 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotif];
                 [app endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
                 bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
             }
     });        
 }];
```

Comment: This is not possible with the current SDK.

Comment: That is not true, because https://itunes.apple.com/nl/app/sleep-cycle-alarm-clock/id320606217?mt=8 is exactly doing this.

Comment: Do you have the app? The app needs to be active, foreground, when using.

Comment: Yes I have and it works on the background: http://www.sleepcycle.com/faq/does-sleep-cycle-function-in-the-background-background-mode/

Comment: Have not been using the 4.0 version sorry, but the fact that the  redbar will be displaid, means they are mis using an API method. Sound to me like sound recording.

Comment: @rckoenes They use it correctly.  Part of the feature is to record you while you sleep to inform you of whatever noise you make.

Answer (score -1):

To run your app infinitely in background, you need to provide the UIBackgroundModes value in Info.plist file.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW20